# systemd[1]: Job raspi-config.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start

Tags: systemd, raspberry-pi, raspbian

I see these errors in the startup log of Raspberry Pi running Raspbian. What do you think these errors indicate and what should be done about them?

```
systemd[1]: Job raspi-config.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Job kbd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
systemd[1]: Job console-setup.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
```

I recently created a new user and deleted the default user `'pi'`, I'm not sure if these errors have their origin there.

Here is the log section, note that the above errors are interspersed:

```
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on raspi-config.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on remote-fs.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on mnt-ds415.mount/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on network.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on dhcpcd.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job raspi-config.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Job raspi-config.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on kbd.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on remote-fs.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on mnt-ds415.mount/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on network.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on dhcpcd.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi kernel: usb 1-1.2: new full-speed USB device number 4 using dwc_otg
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job kbd.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Job kbd.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found ordering cycle on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on sysinit.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on console-setup.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on remote-fs.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on mnt-ds415.mount/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on network.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on dhcpcd.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Found dependency on basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Breaking ordering cycle by deleting job console-setup.service/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Job console-setup.service/start deleted to break ordering cycle starting with basic.target/start
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Expecting device dev-ttyAMA0.device...
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Started Forward Password Requests to Wall Directory Watch.
Nov 26 22:11:58 raspberrypi systemd[1]: Starting Remote File Systems (Pre).
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This has to do with the fact that Debian's migration to systemd wasn't done perfectly for Debian Jessie. Since Raspbian is based on Debian, it has the same issues. The problem is that not all jobs in rcS.d have a corresponding systemd unit, and that init scripts in later runlevels still expect that everything in rcS.d has executed by the time they get to run. To ensure this assumption is valid, the systemd packages in Debian add a 'sysinit' unit, which depends on everything in rcS.d, and on which everything in later runlevels depends (directly or indirectly).

Unfortunately, this workaround retains concepts that systemd does not know about, and as a result this may lead to circular dependencies, as you can see here. One release goal for the next Debian release is to get rid of that workaround and the issues it causes.

For you personally, there isn't much you can do. You can tweak the dependencies if you like, but unless it causes problems with services not starting properly, I wouldn't do so. If it does cause such problems, it's probably also better to file a bug than to fix it yourself, since you wouldn't be the only one experiencing these issues...

Comment: Thanks for clarifying this! I will see if I can contribute by submitting a bug report.